# Subtracting values of a data frame based on a condition for another data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames with same dimension. One data frame (df1) consists of "1" and "0", while the other data frame (df2) has varying values. I want to create a new data frame (df3) by subtracting df2 values based on a condition. The condition is that whenever there is "1" in df1, this location should be identified in df2 (e.g. its row 1st, col 4th). Now value of df2 in the preceding column (row 1st, col 3rd) should be considered as a base {0.98}, and the values in next two columns (row 1st, col 4th {0.6} and col 5th {0.75}) should be subtracted one by one from this base value.
It is explained in a sample below:

```
df1:
 ID    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009
 1      NA      NA      0       1       0
 2      NA      NA      0       1       1
 3       0      0       0       NA      0
 4       0      1       0       0       1

df2:
 ID    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009
 1      NA     0.7     0.98     0.6     0.75
 2      NA     0.2     0.43     0.3     0.5
 3     0.1    -0.98    0.01     0.09    0.1
 4     0.05    -0.1    0.05     0.12    0.23
```

I want df3 to be as follows after subtraction:

```
df3:
 ID    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009
 1      NA      NA      0     -0.38    -0.23
 2      NA      NA      0     -0.13     0.07
 3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 4      0     -0.15     0       0       0.11
```

Here row3 is all NA because there is no "1" in df1, so no subtraction.

I want to use "which" function to identify the location but the subtraction from preceding column is making it a bit complicated for me. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks. Saba

Comment: Imho: It might be helpful to show how exactly some of the values in `df3` are calculated.

Comment: could you pls `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)`?

Comment: OP provided enough information about df1, df2 or how df3 are calculated (except NAs in df3). However this is not a simple task since there are subscription out of bounds cases for last column base values. I tried to get a solution with matrix indexing, it turned out to be quite cumbersome. If your data size is not huge, maybe a for loop is much simpler to implement.

Comment: @lukeA:  I try to explain the output of df3. In df1, there is a value "1" in row 1 and col 4. I have located the same cell in df2 where the value is 0.6. Now the preceding column's value "0.98" is the base, and I have subtracted next two values, "0.6" and "0.75" from 0.98. In this way row 1 of df3 is "NA" when df1 is NA, "0" when its the base cell and has values  "-0.38" and "-0.23" after subtraction. Whereas, row 3 is all "NA" because there is no "1" in this row of df1.

Comment: Basically I need to consider the cell where there is "1" in df1, and subtract the same and next cell's values from the preceding one in df2.

Comment: @dracodoc The data set is quite huge.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, thanks for clarifying. One last thing: Why is `df3[4,"2008"]` zeroed and not `df3[2,"2008"]`? Both have a `1` in `df1[c(2,4),"2009"]`. Overall, a `for` loop is probably the easiest choice to replicate your algorithm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The result I got is different from OP's example, because this case is not defined clearly:

df[2, 5] and df[2, 6] are both 1, but OP's df3 seemed only take df[2, 5] as base and ignored df[2, 6]. My code will use every place that have 1 value as base and reduce it. If OP was expecting different behavior, can OP define the rule for this case more clearly?

Set up data

```
s1 <- "ID    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009
1      NA      NA      0       1       0
2      NA      NA      0       1       1
3       0      0       0       NA      0
4       0      1       0       0       1"

s2 <- "ID    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009
 1      NA     0.7     0.98     0.6     0.75
2      NA     0.2     0.43     0.3     0.5
3     0.1    -0.98    0.01     0.09    0.1
4     0.05    -0.1    0.05     0.12    0.23"
# data.table is only used for reading data, df1 and df2 are regular data.frame
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread(s1, header = TRUE, data.table = FALSE)
df2 <- fread(s2, header = TRUE, data.table = FALSE)
```

Calculate index for each step, combine all changes into one changes matrix, set other position to NA. Note I added columns in left and right to avoid subscription outbound problem.

```
# remove the ID column since it also have value of 1
df1_values <- df1[, 2:ncol(df1)]
df2_values <- df2[, 2:ncol(df2)]
# add extra columns to avoid subscription out of bounds
df1_values <- cbind(0, df1_values, 0, 0)
df2_values <- cbind(0, df2_values, 0, 0)
ones_index <- which(df1_values == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
one_column_shift <- matrix(c(0, 1), nrow = nrow(ones_index), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
base_index <- ones_index - one_column_shift
zero_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df1_values), ncol = ncol(df1_values))
base_matrix <- zero_matrix
base_matrix[base_index] <- df2_values[base_index]
col2_matrix <- zero_matrix
col2_matrix[base_index + one_column_shift] <- df2_values[base_index]
col3_matrix <- zero_matrix
col3_matrix[base_index + one_column_shift + one_column_shift] <- df2_values[base_index]
changes_matrix <- base_matrix + col2_matrix + col3_matrix
changes_matrix[which(changes_matrix == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)] <- NA
result <- df2_values - changes_matrix
result <- cbind(ID = df1[, 1], result[, 2:(ncol(result) - 2)])

> result
  ID 2005  2006 2007  2008  2009
1  1   NA    NA    0 -0.38 -0.23
2  2   NA    NA    0 -0.43 -0.23
3  3   NA    NA   NA    NA    NA
4  4    0 -0.15    0  0.00  0.11
```

benchmark

```
set.seed(101)
df1 <- data.frame(1:10000, matrix(sample(c(NA,0,1), 10000*7, replace = TRUE), ncol = 7))
df2 <- data.frame(1:10000, matrix(rnorm(10000*7), ncol = 7))

Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 selected_code 30.28814 37.44009 81.45066 38.27878 41.1185 264.1638    10
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the code.. although it did not give the exact output, but I managed to obtain the required results by using a part of  this code. It was really useful. Thanks

Comment: In fact, @dracodoc  I shall be really thankful if you kindly have a look at the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864565/conditional-subtraction-of-a-cells-value-from-preceding-12-cells-observations.   Your detailed step by step coding has really helped me, therefore I am looking for the same kind of coding for the problem mentioned in the link. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast `base R` solution:

```
MakeDF3 <- function(dfB, dfN) {  ## dfB --> Binary, dfN --> Numeric
    di <- dim(dfB); n <- di[1]; m <- di[2]
    dfOut <- data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, m*n), nrow = n))
    mBool <- matrix(rep(TRUE, m*n), nrow = n)
    myNames <- names(dfB)
    names(dfOut) <- myNames
    ## Here is the speed increase... i.e. looping over columns as opposed to rows
    for (j in 3:(m-1L)) {
        myOne <- which(dfB[,j]==1)
        myRow <- intersect(myOne, which(mBool[,j-1L]))
        dfOut[myRow,j-1L] <- 0
        mBool[myRow,j-1L] <- FALSE
        for (i in j:(j+1L)) {
            myRow <- intersect(myOne, which(mBool[,i]))
            dfOut[myRow,i] <- dfN[myRow,i]-dfN[myRow,j-1L]
            mBool[myRow,i] <- FALSE
        }
    }
    myOne <- which(dfB[,m]==1)
    myRow <- intersect(myOne,which(mBool[,m-1L]))
    dfOut[myRow,m-1L] <- 0
    myRow <- intersect(myOne,which(mBool[,m]))
    dfOut[myRow,m] <- dfN[myRow,m]-dfN[myRow,m-1L]
    dfOut[,1L] <- dfB[,1L]
    dfOut
}
```

Here is the example output:

```
df1 <- data.frame(1:4,c(NA, NA, 0, 0),c(NA, NA, 0, 1),c(0, 0, 0, 0), c(1, 1, NA, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(1:4,c(NA, NA, 0.1, 0.05),c(0.7,0.2,-0.98,-0.1),c(0.98,0.43,0.01,0.05), c(0.6,0.3,0.09,0.12), c(0.75,0.5,0.1,0.23))
names(df2) <- c("ID", as.character(2005:2009))
names(df1) <- c("ID", as.character(2005:2009))
MakeDF3(df1, df2)
  ID 2005  2006 2007  2008  2009
1  1   NA    NA    0 -0.38 -0.23
2  2   NA    NA    0 -0.13  0.07
3  3   NA    NA   NA    NA    NA
4  4   0  -0.15    0  0.00  0.11
```

Here is a larger example:

```
set.seed(101)
df3 <- data.frame(1:10000, matrix(sample(c(NA,0,1), 10000*7, replace = TRUE), ncol = 7))
df4 <- data.frame(1:10000, matrix(rnorm(10000*7), ncol = 7))
names(df3) <- c("ID", as.character(2005:2011))
names(df4) <- c("ID", as.character(2005:2011))
df5 <- MakeDF3(df3, df4)
```

Here is an brief explanation of how the algorithm works. From the OP's example, we can infer that a "base" from a smaller column number takes precedence when determining output. We know this, because `df1[2,c("2008","2009")] = 1 1` and the resulting data frame for the rows/columns effected is: `df3[2,c("2007","2008","2009")] = 0  -0.13  0.07`. If this were not the case, then `df3[2,"2008"]` would be 0 because `df1[2,"2009"] = 1`.  This is how my algorithm works. Basically, I loop over the columns and I only update rows that have not been previously calculated (this is determined with the `mBool` matrix).

```
head(df3)
  ID 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
1  1    0    1   NA    0    1    0    1
2  2   NA    0    1    0    1    1    0
3  3    1    0   NA    1   NA    0    0
4  4    0    0   NA    1   NA   NA   NA
5  5   NA    0    1   NA    0    1    1
6  6   NA    1    0   NA    0    0    0

head(round(df4, 2))
  ID  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011
1  1 -0.61  1.56 -0.60  0.58 -1.70 -0.86  0.25
2  2  0.37 -1.59  1.25 -1.46  0.38  1.40  2.16
3  3 -0.11 -0.39 -0.04 -1.04  1.09 -2.25  0.50
4  4  0.15 -0.34  0.97  1.19 -0.90  0.62  0.32
5  5  0.61 -0.10  0.17 -0.10  0.33 -0.20  1.87
6  6  1.87 -0.72 -1.52 -1.06  1.13 -0.23 -1.13

head(round(df5,2))
  ID 2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010 2011
1  1    0  2.16  0.01  0.00 -2.28 -1.44 1.11
2  2   NA  0.00  2.84  0.13  1.84  2.86 1.78   ### Note that 2.16 - 0.38 = 1.78 (see df3[2,"2010"] above)
3  3   NA    NA  0.00 -1.00  1.14    NA   NA
4  4   NA    NA  0.00  0.22 -1.87    NA   NA
5  5   NA  0.00  0.27  0.01  0.00 -0.53 1.54
6  6    0 -2.58 -3.38    NA    NA    NA   NA
```

Here are some benchmarks with reservations (although they don't produce identical objects, there outputs are similar enough to warrant efficiency comparison):

```
microbenchmark(MakeDF3(df3,df4),Dracodoc(df3,df4))
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 MakeDF3(df3, df4) 16.54374 19.01940 26.06108 20.23607 21.38977 168.8745   100  a 
Dracodoc(df3, df4) 26.64295 30.79689 59.82243 33.50883 38.02572 191.6978   100   b
```